# getReference() in Doctrine using other field than primary key

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, lazy-loading

Is there any way to use the Symfony2's:

`EntityManager::getReference($entityName, $id)`

With some other field than a Primary Key?

---

Some code:

I have an entity:

```
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(name="my_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $myId;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="child")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *      name="tcb_category_relations",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_category_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    protected $child;
```

Which have a many to many relation to itself. This way, I make tree structures.

The thing is, $myId is much more important to and *static* - this id is not auto generated. So in case of import data, whoose can looks like this csv:

```
| my_id | my_id_parent |
| 1     | 0            | 
| 4     | 1            |
| 5     | 1            |
| 7     | 5            | \ my_id could be unique!
| 7     | 4            | /
| 8     | 7            |
```

MyId is not unique, because any category can have multiple parents. So I can't use it as my primary key. I need to find reference for `Category` using the myId because while data import I need to flush entity manager every time after single category insert and every time run `$em->find()`.

Of course I could use `$em->getReference()` but it's based on primary key and I don't know pk in data import.

Comment: You could do something around EntityManagerDecorator which is not recommendable. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you please add the context of the code? (does it come from a fixture?)

Comment: Post updated. Actually for now I'm trying to import some data into categories in fixture, but later I will provide some interface

Comment: Don't you use `$id`? It seems to be auto-generated and it should be unique. Can you please show the code of your fixtures?

Comment: That's because $myId is much more important for me. My category can be duplicated against $id. I make category: `$c = new Cat(MyId 5);` and then I want to add parent to it: `$c->addParent($em->getReference('Cat', MyId 10));` I cannot make a reference to id 10, because it is not a primary key. My input data comes like in the csv above